# How do I capitalize the first letter of day in DateFormat in French?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I am using `FRENCH` Language in my mobile.

```
DateFormat('MMMMEEEEd').format(DateTime.now())
```

It prints `vendredi 11 novembre`

Expected output => `Vendredi 11 novembre`

Is there any way to capitalize first letter without using string methods?

**I don't want to capitalize the first letter of string with `toUpperCase()` method**

Comment: OK. so the french days are standardised. the only way is manually capitalize the first letter!

Answer (score 1):

The french weekday is lowercase in standard. So there is no function to make it uppercase. It will break the standardisation rules. You need to handle it by your self.

[Capitalize in French](https://www.thoughtco.com/use-of-french-capitalization-4085543)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

void main(){
  getDate(String lang){
    switch (lang){
      case 'fr':
        String date;
        initializeDateFormatting('fr_FR', null).then((_) => {
          date = DateFormat.MMMMEEEEd(lang).format(DateTime.now()),
          date = date.replaceRange(
            0,
            1, 
            date.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(),
          ),
          print(date)
        });
        break;
      case 'en':
        initializeDateFormatting('en_US', null).then((_) => {
          print(DateFormat.MMMMEEEEd(lang).format(DateTime.now()))
        });
        break;
    }
  }
  
  getDate('fr');
  getDate('en');
}
```

Output:

```
Vendredi 11 novembre
Friday, November 11
```

Comment: So the only way is -> manually uppercase the first character?

Comment: I can understand your frustration. But your wish is against the grammatical standard from the. So you need to customize it if you need it different from standard

Answer (score 0):

You can create subString

```dart
final data = "vendredi 11 novembre";

if (data.length > 1) { //just making sure string length
  final result = data[0].toUpperCase() + data.substring(1);

  print(result); //Vendredi 11 novembre
}
```

You can also create extension or method. More about [`String`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/String-class.html)

Comment: I don't want to use the `toUpperCase()` method

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: I have two languages in my app. french and english.
In english it works fine but in french it doesn't

Comment: How about assci conversion

Comment: I don't want to complicate things. I am just looking for
`Is there any way to Capitalize first letter of Day in French using DateFormat` ?

Comment: Sorry I cant test with French, can you update the question

Comment: what update? its seems fine

Comment: I mean, mentioning the language(French) might give more focus, I am also curious about this question, bookmark it  :)